# Javascript within HTML not alternating between two images as desired

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on [CS50's PSet 8](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2022/psets/8/homepage/) on VS Code's web editor, and I want the homepage of the website to alternate between two different images of me. With the given code (see below), the website will alternate the image only once, changing the src from the original value of "author.JPG" to "author2.jpg" but never changing it back. Any ideas what might be happening? I already made sure that all the names match exactly and such, so I think it's a problem with the code, not the syntax.

Thanks in advance!

```
      // Toggles source of image

      function rotate()
      {
          let pic = document.querySelector('img');
          if (pic.src == 'author2.jpg')
          {
            pic.src = 'author.JPG';
          }
          else
          {
            pic.src = 'author2.jpg';
          }
      }

      // Rotate every 500ms
      window.setInterval(rotate, 3000);

  </script>
    <title>My Webpage</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <a href="index.html">Home</a>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <a href="aboutme.html">About Me</a>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <a href="myprojects.html">My projects</a>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <a href="resume.html">Resume</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <img src = "author.JPG" alt="The author of this web page" width="600" height="500">
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

The actual `src` value isn't what you think it is.  The browser is "correcting" it to a full URL.  You can observe this by logging it to the console in your function:

```
let pic = document.querySelector('img');
console.log(pic.src);
```

Instead of looking for an exact match, just check if the `src` [ends with](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith) the value:

```
if (pic.src.endsWith('author2.jpg'))
```